# How to replace the data into a line of a file?

Tags: python-2.7

I've a file as follow

```
sys.test1.username = user1
sys.test1.pwd = 1234
sys.test2.username = user2
sys.test2.pwd = 1234
```

I want to change the pwd of sys.test1.pwd as sys.test1.pwd = 4321

read file

```
with open (tempfile, 'r') as tempFile:
            return self.parse_cfg (self, tempFile.readlines ())
```

this is searching the sys.test1.pwd and getting the value.

```
def parse_cfg (self, lines):
        """ Parse ubnt style configuration into a dict"""
        ret_dict = {}
        for line in lines:
            line = line.strip () # remove new lines
            if not line: continue # skip empty lines


            key, value = line.split ('=') # key = value
            print "key %s" %key 

            if key == 'sys.test1.pwd':
                key = key.strip ()            
                value = value.strip ()

                # logic to parse mainkey.subkey.subkey structure into a dict
                keys = key.split ('.') 
                tempo = ret_dict
                for each in keys[:-1]:
                    tempo.setdefault (each, {})
                    tempo = tempo[each]
                tempo[keys[-1]] = value

                break

        return ret_dict
```

But I don't know how to write the sys.test1.pwd=4321 into file. please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
import re

def searchReplace(file, search, replace):
    with open (file,'r') as f:
        f_content= f.read()
    # Re to search and replace
    f_content = (re.sub(search, replace, f_content))
    #write file with replaced content
    with open (file,'w') as f:
        f.write(f_content)


searchReplace("file.txt","sys.test1.pwd = 1234","sys.test1.pwd = 4321")
```

Comment: Nice solution. You might want to pass raw strings for the regex, just in case... Otherwise if you wanted to do it literally I think you could just use `.replace`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what is your exact question, so I'll try to answer to my best understanding.

Do you want to write it to the same file or to a different file?

Basically to write to a file you need to open a file with write permission -

```
termFileWrite = open (tempfile, 'w')

termFileWrite.write(yourText)
```

If you are asking about writing to a file in the format above then it should be something like:

```
myString = ""
for k,v in dict.iteritems():
    myString+=k+"="+v+"\n"
termFileWrite.write(myString)
```